# Volley request fails, if string's length is long

Tags: android, android-volley, multipart

I am trying to make a multi-part request using volley. It works perfectly when the length of user entered address and title in edit text is small; but it will fails if user enter more text in edit texts.

Volley Multipart Request contains parameters as curl url. I am not able to understand what is the actual problem.

```
final JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();

        jsonBody.put("CategoryName", categories.get(categorySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).getCategoryName().replace(" ", "_"));
        jsonBody.put("SubCategoryName", subCategories.get(subCategorySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).replace(" ", "_"));
        jsonBody.put("City", "Rabwah");
        jsonBody.put("Address", etAddress.getText().toString());
        jsonBody.put("ProductTitle", etTitle.getText().toString());
        jsonBody.put("Description", etDescription.getText().toString());
        jsonBody.put("Price", Integer.parseInt(etPrice.getText().toString()));
        jsonBody.put("flgNegotiable", negotiableCheckBox.isChecked());
        jsonBody.put("flgUsed", usedCheckBox.isChecked());
        jsonBody.put("flgNew", newCheckBox.isChecked());
        jsonBody.put("ContactNumber", Integer.parseInt(etNumber.getText().toString()));
        jsonBody.put("UserID", preferences.getInt("id", 2));
        String url;
        if (adsModel != null) {
            jsonBody.put("ProductAddID", adsModel.getProductAddID());
            url = UrlConstants.updatepost + "?Json=" + jsonBody;

        } else {
            url = UrlConstants.submitAd + "?Json=" + jsonBody;
        }
        VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                Log.d("onResponse: ", response.toString());
                try {
                    k.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                Toasty.success(context, "Ad Posted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {



                try {
                    k.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                Toasty.error(context, "some error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                error.printStackTrace();

            }
        }) {


            @Override
            protected Map<String, VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart> getByteData() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();



                    params.put("file1", new DataPart("file_avatar.jpg", getbyte(resultUri1), "image/jpeg"));




                return params;
            }


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                params.put("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                return params;
            }
        };


        RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue();

        requestQueue.add(multipartRequest);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

please help me i will be very thank full

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

In build:gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

Declare Globally in onCreate method

```
RequestQueue requestQueue;
```

In onCreate():

```
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


String url = "www.yourwebsite.com/example.php";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            jsonParser(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(CreatePostQuery.this, "Error! Please try again later...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            MyData.put("userid", userid);
            MyData.put("posttext", posttext);
            MyData.put("email", email);
            return MyData;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void jsonParser(String jsontext) {
    try {
        JSONObject emp = (new JSONObject(jsontext));
        String result = emp.getString("result");
        if (result.equals("successful")) {
            Toast.makeText(CreatePostQuery.this, "Post uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (result.equals("error")) {
            Toast.makeText(CreatePostQuery.this, "Error! Please try again later...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are appending the data to the url hence increasing its length. Some servers have limits to the length of the url and that could be the problem. Since you are making a POST request why not put the data in the request body instead as it can handle larger amounts of data.

Comment: server is designed in that way to send json in url